# making comment editable - Jquery click function not working

Tags: jquery, html

I printed Comments (given on an Image ) like this

```
         <div class=\"comment\"  id='".$query['C_id']."'>

         <p>Comment from 
           <span class=\"namecomment\">'".$query['c_name']."'</span> 
           <span>( ".$sWhen." )</span>:
         </p>
         <p><span id='first_".$query['C_id']."'>".$query['c_text']."</span></p>

         <textarea name=\"comment\"  class=\"editbox\"id='first_input_".$query['C_id']."'>".$query['c_text']."</textarea></div>
```

html looks like in the end like this

```
<div class="pright">
    <div id=\"commentdiv\">
        <span id=\"commentspsn\"></span>
        <div id=\"comments_list\">  
        <div class=\"comment\"  id='12'>

             <p>Comment from 
               <span class=\"namecomment\">'ali'</span> 
               <span>( date )</span>:
             </p>
             <p><span id='first_1'>this</span></p>

             <textarea name=\"comment\"  class=\"editbox\"id='first_input_1'>this</textarea></div>
</div>
        </div>
```

(textarea is on display="none")

it looks like this 
[image: Comments]

I tried many ways to select this comment and get this attr('id') 
i am missing something due to that i couldnt do that

jquery code i am trying

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".pright").click(function(){
   alert ($(this).find('.comment').attr('id'));
  });
});


    });
    </script>
```

i am able to get alert by click to div .pright but it is not right i need to click on .comment to get its attribute `id

Answer (score 1):

Try to use **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** for dynamically created elements:

```
$(document.body).on('click','#comments_list .comment',function() {
    var ID=$(this).attr('id');
    alert(ID);
});
```

Comment: it is not working i have a question too i am using this in head tag    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 is it ok for this jquery action ?

Comment: Yes, you need to include jQuery. Did you receive any error in the browser console?

Comment: nope no error in console let me console.log for that

Comment: it is working now on click alert but can you see my modified question please?

Answer (score 0):

Without doing any tinkering the first thing I see is a missing `;` so try this.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
     $("#comments_list .comment").click(function()
     {
         var ID=$(this).attr('id');
         alert (ID);
     });
});
```